# Where to ask about oxygen producing plants in zero G?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about plants in no-gravity environment. I know plants can be grows in soil or in liquid substance filled with vital components for plant growth. What I don't get is how soil or liquid doesn't scatter around without gravity. Is there a different solution for plants in space? Or are the plants contained well enough so the growing medium doesn't scatter?

There's Space Exploration, but I don't think this is the right site for this. Gardening doesn't seem to be either.

Comment: Growing medium adheres to itself.  So does liquid; it assumes the shape of a sphere (the smallest possible surface area) in zero gravity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is on topic over at Space Exploration as it is likely to be key to longer term space exploration - in fact there may already be a related question there.

In fact a quick look at the plants tag shows 9 [related questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=plants).

Answer (score 3):

https://physics.stackexchange.com/

From their [on-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section:

> please stick to the following topics:
>
> - Explanations of observed physical or astronomical phenomena
>   Why does one experience a short pull in the wrong direction when a vehicle stops?

Comment: The other answer points to a better website.

Comment: A question can be perfectly ontopic on two different sites; there are no absolute borders.

Comment: I can't see how this fits to physics.se, however